# WPF Window OnShown event

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a bit of a strange question but working with Microsoft products you can expect all sorts of surprises. I have a `Window` in my `WPF` application that I need periodically show and hide. The window is too heavy and it takes a lot of time to init all its resources so I don't want to create/delete it every time.
After the window is shown I need some event will be fired.
The workflow is as following:

```
var myWindow = new MyWindow();
myWindow.OnShow += delegate() {  }
myWindow.ShowDialog(); // here I want OnShow will be fired

// then I call to Hide() inside the window

myWindow.ShowDialog(); // here I want OnShow will be fired again
```

I tried several methods that I found on the Internet:

- `ContentRendered` event. Fired only the first time, doesn't work on showing a hidden window
- `Loaded` event - the same a above
- `IsVisibleChanged` - fires immediately after calling `ShowDialog`, not after the window is really shown.

as a result I don't know how to implement such a simple task.

My environment:

- .NET v. 4.7.2
- Windows 10 x64

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37975171/12354911) answer might help. And `Activated` event seems like what you seek.

Comment: Thanks @Eldar, that works ae expected!